# Find modules required by a python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, perl, scripting

There is some directory with files and folders having some programming modules like Perl modules, python files and some other shell files. There is one main file in python(.py) to do some task which requires some of the modules not all.

Consider a scenario where the main python files import some other python files and in the code its uses os.system('perl perl_filename.pm') and this perl_filename it self calls other perl modules and python files in between.

How do I find the all the files and modules used by this main python file at the end of execution.One solution is to read the code the from the start and finding dependencies by reading the code.But code base is so large that is not feasible.

Comment: If you want to only use shell commands, why did you tag Perl? A Python process will likely not open any Perl files.

Comment: python files can have these commands like os.system("perl filename")

Answer (score 3):

This question is too broad. I think you should have a look at [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/), this will help you finding out dependencies.

```
sfood -fuq main_file.py | sfood-target-files
```

Comment: i want to use only shell commands for that how to do that

Comment: You write your own replacement for `sfood` in pure shell. Probably you will need to reimplement Python, too.

Comment: Reading the code base seems more feasible than implementing sfood. Lets leave sfood for a moment, Can I use debugging module to check sequentially which files are being invoked?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess, **simple, but for sure not the best approach**, is to use `lsof` to display which files are opened by this script. Example:

```
$ sudo lsof | grep 31454 | grep python
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  txt       REG                9,2       4864     660953 /usr/bin/python
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2      11608     785876 /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/resource.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2      24432     785877 /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/selectmodule.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2      22240     785814 /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2       9872     785794 /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_bisectmodule.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2      67296     656787 /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2      12848     670980 /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2      94496     662596 /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2      21376     673621 /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/python/_epoll.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2      14632     785853 /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/fcntlmodule.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2      21608     785817 /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_localemodule.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2       7744     787783 /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/syslog.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2      23784     785886 /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/zlibmodule.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2     123608     785806 /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2      12680     785823 /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_randommodule.so
carbon-ca 31454      carbon  mem       REG                9,2
```